# Dynamic IP Restriction to add ip addresses, vnet and service tag terraform azure

Tags: azure-web-app-service, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

So far with a help on previous topics I was able to deploy App service with IP Restriction with the following code:

Variable

```
locals {
ip_address_list2 = [            {     
                  ip_add : "20.20.20.3/32",
                  subnet_id = null,
                  service_tag               = null,
                  prior : "140",
                  name = "test1"
            },
           {     
                  ip_add : "10.10.10.2/32",
                  subnet_id = null,
                  service_tag               = null,
                  prior : "141",
                  name = "test2"
            },
            {
                 ip_add : "0.0.0.0/0",
                 subnet_id = null,
                 service_tag               = "AppService"
                 prior : "142",
                 name = "Service_Tag"
            }]}
```

App Service:

```
  site_config {
  dynamic "ip_restriction" {
for_each = local.ip_address_list2
  content {
    ip_address  = ip_restriction.value["ip_add"]
    action                    = "Allow"
    priority                  = ip_restriction.value["prior"]
    virtual_network_subnet_id = ip_restriction.value["subnet_id"]
    service_tag = ip_restriction.value["service_tag"]
    name = ip_restriction.value["name"]
  }}}
```

But if I add the following variable for the subnet I receive error:

```
        {
             ip_add : "0.0.0.0/0",
             subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id,
             service_tag               = null
             prior : "143",
             name = "VirtualNetwork"
        }
```

[Screenshot Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeaMY.png)

> Error: creating App Service "hook-service" (Resource Group
> "RG-DEV-TEST"): web.AppsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending
> request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Code="BadRequest"
> Message="IpSecurityRestriction is invalid.  Only IpAddress or
> VnetSubnetResourceId property must be specified."
> Details=[{"Message":"IpSecurityRestriction is invalid.  Only IpAddress
> or VnetSubnetResourceId property must be
> specified."},{"Code":"BadRequest"},{"ErrorEntity":{"Code":"BadRequest","ExtendedCode":"51021","Message":"IpSecurityRestriction
> is invalid.  Only IpAddress or VnetSubnetResourceId property must be
> specified.","MessageTemplate":"{0} is invalid.
> {1}","Parameters":["IpSecurityRestriction","Only IpAddress or
> VnetSubnetResourceId property must be specified."]}}] │  │   with
> azurerm_app_service.hook-service, │   on main.tf line 474, in resource
> "azurerm_app_service" "hook-service": │  474: resource
> "azurerm_app_service" "hook-service" {

**NOTE**: validation with only **terraform plan** can be completed without error. The error is observed only after **terraform apply**

Thank you

Comment: Hello @Igor, as per the error message , it ,clearly says that you can use either ip_address or Virtual network while setting the ip_restrictions not both. so if you add ip_address then vnet,subnet will become null by default and if virtual network is provided then ip_address will become null.

Comment: Thank you for responding on my problem. How can I avoid or combine this kind of configuration ? I know its only few clicks on the portal in order to create this ip_restriction but I want to have it automatic creation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use something like below:

```
locals {
 ip_address_list = [            {     
                  ip_add : "20.20.20.3/32",
                  prior : "140",
                  name = "test1"
            },
           {     
                  ip_add : "10.10.10.2/32",
                  prior : "141",
                  name = "test2"
            }
 ]
ip_address_list2=[            {
                 subnet = "${data.azurerm_subnet.name.id}" ,
                 name = "test3"
                 prior ="143"
            }]
            }
```

Then you can use :

```
  site_config {
    dynamic "ip_restriction"{
      for_each=local.ip_address_list
      content{
        ip_address  = ip_restriction.value["ip_add"]
    action                    = "Allow"
    priority                  = ip_restriction.value["prior"]
    name = ip_restriction.value["name"]
      }
    }
dynamic "ip_restriction"  {
  for_each = local.ip_address_list2
  content{
    name = ip_restriction.value["name"]
    virtual_network_subnet_id = ip_restriction.value["subnet"]
    priority = ip_restriction.value["prior"]
  }
}
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note:**  For IP_address restriction you have to provide ip_add , Prior and name. But for subnet restriction you have to give only subnet_id, prior and name. With providing service_tag it will error out with same error.

Comment: This is amazing: I have split between ip_address_list ( added only ip addresses) ip_address_list2 ( added only Service_Tag ) ip_address_list3 (Added Virtual Subnet with Service endpoint tested as following: <subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id> and is is working) and all of the required restrictions are available on the portal.

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this in some of our older terraform modules

Terraform : **v0.13.2**

AzureRM :   **v2.42.0**

I believe the issue is resolved in the newer major versions but when I deleted the state/app and redeployed it worked.